# What memcpy_s return error 404 mean

Tags: c

When I use `memcpy_s()` to copy data, I get a return value of 404. What does this mean? I have checked that the destination buffer size is larger than the number of bytes to be copied.

Comment: Please post the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that shows the problem, and where you get your "return value" from.

Comment: Error 404? Everyone knows that means 'no such file or directory' `:-)`

Comment: And: 404 is typically an [HTTP Error](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_404) and has nothing to do with C/C++.

Comment: The [man page for `memcpy_s`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wes2t00f.aspx) states it may return `EINVAL` or `ERANGE` when an error occurrs. Neither has the value `404`.

Comment: @WeatherVane: True, but there is another error code that does - `ESOVRLP`.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I see your answer. With MSVC (which I thought is the home of the `***_s` functions) I get the error "'ESOVRLP': undeclared identifier" (even with `#include <errno.h>`) when I try to print its value. It is not documented on the `memcpy_s` man page.

Comment: @RemyLebeau the MSVC function `memcpy_s` returns `0` when the source and destination overlap. Its man page only says the behaviour is undefined.

Comment: @WeatherVane: AFAIK, Microsoft does not define `ESOVRLP` in any header file.  I found it online, but it fits with the described issue. Of course, the OP never said if MSVC is even being used or not. Just add the `#define` to your code manually if needed. As for "*the MSVC function memcpy_s returns 0 when the source and destination overlap*", it is not following the C11 specification, which forbids overlap. Even MSDN explicitly says not to use `memcpy_s` for overlapping memory. So I would consider the return value of 0 to be a bug and fall into the "undefined behavior" category.

Comment: @RemyLebeau that's more or less what I said: MSVC says it is undefined behaviour if the ranges overlap, and to use the `*move*` versions of `memcpy` and `memcpy_s`. The value `ESOVRLP` is not present in any MSVC header file. I don't see the point of defining it, unless you put a wrapper round the library functions. If `memcpy_s` returned `ESOVRLP` that would be defined, not undefined behaviour.

Comment: @WeatherVane: again, *we don't know* if the OP is using MSVC or not. Since the OP is getting a return value that is undocumented by Microsoft for behavior that is undefined in MSVC, it stands to reason that the OP is probably not using MSVC, but some other compiler that has a more C11-compliant runtime that validates overlaps.

Comment: @RemyLebeau yes we do. Because MSVC does not return that error code.

Answer (score 4):

`memcpy_s()` is formally defined in the C11 standard ([ISO/IEC 9899:2011](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG14/www/docs/n1570.pdf)), section K.3.7.1.1, which simply states:

> The memcpy_s function returns zero if there was no runtime-constraint violation. Otherwise, a nonzero value is returned.

There is no mention of the specific values that `memcpy_s()` return on error, so they are implementation-defined.

You did not say which compiler you are actually using.

For example, Microsoft's [`memcpy_s()` documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wes2t00f.aspx) for MSVC states that `memcpy_s()` can only return either `EINVAL` or `ERANGE` when an error occurs, and that behavior is undefined if the source and destination overlap.

[MinGW-w64 exhibits this same behavior](https://sourceforge.net/p/mingw-w64/mingw-w64/ci/777c8bffbeb34d499b90254d328e1df7a5fa61ec/tree/mingw-w64-crt/secapi/memcpy_s.c).

However, this behavior is formally forbidden by the `memcpy_s()` definition in ISO/IEC 9899:2011:

> Copying shall not take place between objects that overlap.

In some runtime implementations, there is another error code that may be returned:

```
#define ESOVRLP         ( 404 )       /* overlap undefined           */
```

This error means the source and destination are overlapping.

Since you are getting a return value that is *undocumented* by Microsoft for behavior that is *undefined* in MSVC (and MinGW), it stands to reason that you are probably using some other compiler/runtime that has a more C11-compliant implementation that is returning `ESOVRLP` if overlap is detected (for example, [safeclib does](https://github.com/coruus/safeclib/blob/master/src/safeclib/memcpy_s.c)).